# GET Request Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having and issue with routing GET requests on an API controller, the problem I am having is because I need to have 3 separate methods for GET:

```
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> Get()

public virtual MyViewModel Get(int id)

public virtual MyResponceData<MyViewModel> Get(MyRequestData requestData)
```

If I comment out the 3rd method the other 2 work as expected, however with that one also available I get `{"Message":"An error has occurred."}` which isn’t much help, but as it works when I comment the method I’m assuming it’s a routing issue.
I only have the default routing configured, which is as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Things I've tried thus far:

- Adding `[FromUri]` attribute to the ‘MyRequestData’ argument as I read this may fix the issue.
- Added `[Route("api/controller/otherGet")]` this works but I would rather it route on the parameter if possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After researching this, it doesn't look like its possible (feel free to correct me).

I resolved this in the end by making `Get()` and `Get(MyRequestData requestData)` private and creating an additional get method:

```
public virtual object Get([FromUri]MyRequestData requestData)
```

Then I call the corresponding private `Get` method according to how the `requestData` parameter is set.